# Relatórios em .NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, relatório, reporting-services

Estou migrando um sistema na empresa que utiliza Reporting Services, o que não é utilizado em .NET CORE.

A empresa pediu para eu ir atrás de ferramentas parecidas com ReportService que fosse gratuita e aplicável em .NET Core. Eu pesquisei algumas e só encontrei algumas pagas ou outras que não me atendem.

Vocês conhecem alguma ferramenta que se assemelha ao ReportServices para aplicar em .NET CORE?